# Recursively enumerable sets as image of a function

Tags: logic, computability

I want to show the following claim: An infinite recursively enumerable subset of the natural numbers is the image of an injective recursive function.

What I know is that given a r.e. set $A\subset \mathbb{N}$, by definition I get a recursive set $B\subset \mathbb{N}^2$ s.t. $A=\{a\in\mathbb{N}:\exists m\in\mathbb{N}s.t.(a,m)\in B\}$.
To show that this is the image of a recursive function I can define $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with $f(n)=((n)_0,(n)_1)$ if there exists an $m$ such that $(n,m)\in B$, and $f(n)=k$ otherwise, where k is any element of A and $(n)_i=\beta(n,i+1)$.
This function is only injective if $A=\mathbb{N}$ though.

Any hints?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: Hint: try to check in parallel for every $n\in\Bbb N$ whether there is $m\in\Bbb N$ with $(a,m)\in B$. Every time you find a witness $m$ for $n$, make $n$ the next output of $f$.

Comment: How do I check it though? My guess is that I have to use course-of-values recursion, but I'm not sure as how to apply the concept, and I still lack intuition concerning this topic.

Comment: I would do it like this: first check if $(0,0)\in B$, then if $(1,0),(0,1)\in B$, then if $(2,0),(1,1),(0,2)\in B$ and so on. As soon as you find some $(n,m)\in B$, make $n$ the next output of given function and stop checking further pairs $(n,k)$.

Comment: How can I put this into a closed form though? I need to find a formal proof for the claim.

Comment: There is a difference between having a formal proof and having a closed form. The formal proof can be written in natural language, e.g. English. You just have to describe the computational process in a rigorous way.

Answer (score 1):

One program that will work can be constructed as follows.  First, there is a computable listing of all the pairs $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{N}^2$. For example, the listing might begin $$(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,2), (1,1), (2,0), \ldots$$

On input $n$, your program will search through this enumeration in order until it finds $n$ pairs that are in $B$ and that have different first elements.  Then it will return the first element of the final pair that was found, again using the order on all pairs to decide which was the "last" pair found.

The verification that this is a computable operation relies on the fact that $B$ is computable, so there is an effective way to decide whether each pair is in $B$. Also, because the original set $A$ is infinite, you can show that the program halts for all $n$ - if you run it long enough on input $n$, it must eventually find $n$ different values for the initial element of the pair, or else $A$ would be finite.

You will not produce an *equation* or *formula* for the program - just a description of how it works and a verification that it is correct (and that the method it uses is effective).

Comment: Are you using the word computability in exchange with $\mu$-recursiveness? I can't find anything about just intuitively defining an algorithm in my lecture notes. So I still assume that I have to find equations/formulas which I then have to somehow put together using theorems from the lecture. Do you think this is possible by applying course-of-values recursion.